# Searching jpeg/bmp/pdf image for straight lines, circles and text

Tags: c++, image, algorithm, qt, parsing

I want to create an image parser that shall read an image having following:
1. Straight Lines
2. Circles
3. Arcs
4. Text

**I am open for solutions for any type of image format either jpeg, bmp, or PDF format.**

I have seen QImage documentation. It shall provide me with pixel data that I can store in the form of a 2D matrix. At the moment I shall assume that there are only two colours black and white. White represents empty pixel and black represents a drawn pixel.

So I will have a sparse matrix like

```
0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 1 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

Now I want to decode this matrix and search for the elements. Searching for horizontal and vertical lines is easy because for each element I can just scan its neighbouring row elements and column elements.

How can I search for other elements (angled lines, circles, arcs and possibly text)?

For text I read that QImage has text() function but I don't know for what type of input file it works.

Is there any other library that I can consider?
**Please note that I just want to be able to read the image, processing does not need to be done.**

Is there any other way I can accomplish this? Or am I being too ambitious?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) library. Notice that this is a very difficult problem in general, so you will probably need to do a fair amount of research before getting satisfactory solutions.

Comment: @ComicSansMS OpenCV is a good library. Please consider posting this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Done. Glad you find it useful. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) library.

It provides most of the standard algorithms used in image detection and vision and the code quality of its implementation is quite high in general.

Notice though that this is a very difficult problem in general, so you will probably need to do a fair amount of research before getting satisfactory solutions.

Answer (score 1):

One interesting way of tackling this would be with machine learning systems, such as neural networks and genetic algorithms. Neural nets in particular are very good at pattern matching and are often seen being used for tasks such as handwriting recognition.

There's a lot of information on this if you search for it. [Here's](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16419/AI-Neural-Network-for-beginners-Part-1-of-3) one such article that is an introduction to NNs.

If your input images are always black and white, I don't think it would be too difficult to adapt a code example to get it working.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I haven't ever been introduced to neural networks as yet. I shall check them out.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **[Viola-Jones object detection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework)**.

Though the approach is usually implemented on face detection - the [original article](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/AP06/Papers/viola-IJCV-01.pdf) discusses general object detection, such as your text, circles and lines.

Comment: The wiki page says that it has been implemented in the OpenCV library. So if I decide to use OpenCV, it should have this algorithm's features right? Or do you suggest I go for the actual implementation myself?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal No need to reinvent the wheel, if you find an existing implementation - use it. Unfortunately, I cannot help you - as I amnot familiar with openCV